# Run/Open Chrome Extension in Selenium Webdriver - C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I've got the extension installed and such through selenium, but I can't seem to find a way to actually open the extension to access it's features.

The extension when opened (i.e. icon clicked) opens a toolbar which I can then access through selenium and go about my business.

I'm able to open the extension with its shortcut (SHIFT+ALT+Q) using Keyboard.SendKeys with a UIMap, but it's unreliable and often just decides it doesn't want to open it (no error thrown).

Anyone have any suggestions of other ways to open it?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a code snippet